# How to merge REST call results in Angular app more efficiently

Tags: arrays, angularjs, rest, sharepoint, memory-leaks

I have an Angular SPA running on a SharePoint 2013 page. In the code, I'm using $q to pull data from 10 different SharePoint lists using REST and then merging them into one JSON object for use in a grid. The code runs and outputs the intended merged data but it's leaky and crashes the browser after a while.

Here's the code in the service:

```
factory.getGridInfo = function() { 
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var list_1a = CRUDFactory.getListItems("ListA", "column1,column2,column3");
    var list_1b = CRUDFactory.getListItems("ListB", "column1,column2,column3");
    var list_2a = CRUDFactory.getListItems("ListC", "column4");
    var list_2b = CRUDFactory.getListItems("ListD", "column4");
    var list_3a = CRUDFactory.getListItems("ListE", "column5");
    var list_3b = CRUDFactory.getListItems("ListF", "column5");
    var list_4a = CRUDFactory.getListItems("ListG", "column6");
    var list_4b = CRUDFactory.getListItems("ListH", "column6");
    var list_5a = CRUDFactory.getListItems("ListI", "column7");
    var list_5b = CRUDFactory.getListItems("ListJ", "column7");

    $q.all([list_1a, list_1b, list_2a, list_2b, list_3a, list_3b, list_4a, list_4b, list_5a, list_5b]) 
    .then(function(results){
        var results_1a = results[0].data.d.results;
        var results_1b = results[1].data.d.results;
        var results_2a = results[2].data.d.results;
        var results_2b = results[3].data.d.results;
        var results_3a = results[4].data.d.results;
        var results_3b = results[5].data.d.results;
        var results_4a = results[6].data.d.results;
        var results_4b = results[7].data.d.results;
        var results_5a = results[8].data.d.results;
        var results_5b = results[9].data.d.results;

        var combined_1 = results_1a.concat(results_1b);
        var combined_2 = results_2a.concat(results_2b);
        var combined_3 = results_3a.concat(results_3b);
        var combined_4 = results_4a.concat(results_4b);
        var combined_5 = results_5a.concat(results_5b);

        for(var i = 0; i < combined_1.length; i++){ 
            var currObj = combined_1[i];
            currObj["column4"] = combined_2[i].column4;
            currObj["column5"] = combined_3[i].column5;
            currObj["column6"] = combined_4[i].column6;
            currObj["column7"] = combined_5[i].column7;

            factory.newObjectArray[i] = currObj;

        }
        deferred.resolve(factory.newObjectArray);
    },
    function (error) {
        deferred.reject(error);
    });         
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Here's the REST call in CRUDFactory:

```
factory.getListItems = function (listName, columns){
    var webUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('"+listName+"')/items?$select="+columns+"&$top=5000";
    var options = {
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }, 
        method: 'GET', 
        url: webUrl                 
    };
    return $http(options);
};
```

And then here's the controller bit:

```
$scope.refreshGridData = function(){ 
    $scope.hideLoadingGif = false;
    $scope.GridData = "";
    GlobalFactory.getGridInfo()
    .then(function(){
        $scope.GridData = GlobalFactory.newObjectArray;
        $scope.hideLoadingGif = true;
    });
};
```

**UPDATE 1:** Per request, Here's the HTML (just a simple div that we're using angular-ui-grid on)

```
<div ui-grid="GridOptions" class="grid" ui-grid-selection ui-grid-exporter ui-grid-save-state></div>
```

This code starts by declaring some get calls and then uses $q.all to iterate over the calls and get the data. It then stores the results and merges them down to 5 total arrays. Then, because my list structure is proper and static, I'm able to iterate over one of the merged arrays and pull data from the other arrays into one master array that I'm assigning to factory.newObjectArray, which I'm declaring as a global in my service and using as my grid data source.

The code runs and doesn't kick any errors up but the issue is with (I believe) the "getGridInfo" function. If I don't comment out any of the REST calls, the browser uses 45 MB of data that doesn't get picked up by GC which is then compounded for each click until the session is ended or crashes.  If I comment out all the calls but one, my page only uses 18.4 MB of memory, which is high but I can live with it.

So what's the deal?  Do I need to destroy something somewhere?  If so, what and how? Or does this relate back to the REST function I'm using?

**UPDATE 2:** The return result that the grid is using (the factory.newObjectArray) contains a total of 5,450 items and each item has about 80 properties after the merge. The code above is simplified and shows the pulling of a couple columns per list, but in actuality, I'm pulling 5-10 columns per list.

Comment: I cannot see anything fundamentally wrong with your code. Which browser are you using?

Comment: IE11 or FF 38.2  (no access to Chrome in this environment)

Comment: That's a shame, as chrome has the profiler that can show you what is happening. Can you show the markup? This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25193339/1248716 suggests that leaks are caused by DOM elements that get created via ng-repeat and are not being released

Comment: Yea, IE11 dev tools has a memory profiler too but it's not letting me take any heap snapshots of this page.  Possibly related?  As for markup...The resulting JSON is used to feed a Angular-UI-Grid so the HTML is just a div with a few attributes.

Comment: What does your `factory.newObjectArray` look like?

Comment: Added a couple updates to the question; one showing the div the grid uses and the other discussing the final data source array

Comment: Quick update, I've managed to improve efficiency by roughly 43% by doing 2 things: turning the concats into unshifts and also making the item that's iterated over skinny (making "combined_1" have just one column instead of many).  I'm down to about 25.2 MB from the original 45 MB but it's still leaky and doesn't GC everything on refresh. I'll keep plugging away and will post revised code once I get it down further.

Comment: See my answer below which may help the leaks, by cleaning up variables and minimising the number of arrays and concatenations you were performing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the day you are dealing with a lot of data, so memory problems are potentially always going to be an issue and you should probably consider whether you need to have all the data in memory.

The main goal you should probably be trying to achieve is limiting duplication of arrays, and trying to keep the memory footprint as low as possible, and freeing memory as fast as possible when you're done processing.

Please consider the following. You mention the actual number of columns being returned are more than your example so I have taken that into account.

```
factory.getGridInfo = function () {

  var deferred = $q.defer(),

    // list definitions
    lists = [
      { name: 'ListA', columns: ['column1', 'column2', 'column3'] },
      { name: 'ListB', columns: ['column1', 'column2', 'column3'], combineWith: 'ListA' },
      { name: 'ListC', columns: ['column4'] },
      { name: 'ListD', columns: ['column4'], combineWith: 'ListC' },
      { name: 'ListE', columns: ['column5'] },
      { name: 'ListF', columns: ['column5'], combineWith: 'ListE' },
      { name: 'ListG', columns: ['column6'] },
      { name: 'ListH', columns: ['column6'], combineWith: 'ListG' },
      { name: 'ListI', columns: ['column7'] },
      { name: 'ListJ', columns: ['column7'], combineWith: 'ListI' },
    ],

    // Combines two arrays without creating a new array, mindful of lenth limitations
    combineArrays = function (a, b) {
      var len = b.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < len; i = i + 5000) {
        a.unshift.apply(a, b.slice(i, i + 5000));
      }
    };

  $q.all(lists.map(function (list) { return CRUDFactory.getListItems(list.name, list.columns.join()); }))
  .then(function (results) {

    var listResultMap = {}, var baseList = 'ListA';

    // map our results to our list names
    for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      listResultMap[lists[i].name] = results[i].data.d.results;
    }

    // loop around our lists
    for(var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
      var listName = lists[i].name, combineWith = lists[i].combineWith;
      if(combineWith) {
        combineArrays(listResultMap[combineWith], listResultMap[listName]);
        delete listResultMap[listName];
      }
    }

    // build result
    factory.newObjectArray = listResultMap[baseList].map(function(item) {
      for(var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
        if(list.name !== baseList) {
          for(var c = 0; c < lists[i].columns.length; c++) {
            var columnName = lists[i].columns[c];
            item[columnName] = listResultMap[list.name][columnName];
          }
        }
      }
      return item;
    });

    // clean up our remaining results
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      delete results[i].data.d.results;
      delete results[i];
    }

    deferred.resolve(factory.newObjectArray);

  },
  function (error) {
    deferred.reject(error);
  });
  return deferred.promise;
};
```

Comment: Because of the need for a dynamic grid interaction where users hide/show columns and export various bits of data to Excel, I can't make the data source any smaller.  As for your code, you brought up a couple good techniques that I'm going to try. I'll post the results after I implement them.

Comment: I used your map technique and, with a few tweaks to your unshift method, and a few more to the result builder, I was able to get the initial load down to 19.1 MB, effectively shaving off 8+ MB.The real kicker though is that GC is working better and refreshes are only leaking 1 - 1.2 MB, which could be attributed to ui-router or some other angular element.  Nice work!  Points awarded.

Comment: Bounty expired yesterday...  Sorry Shaun.  I marked yours as answer though and upvoted for what its worth

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped your situation and thanks for the selection.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to add some sort of paging option... It's perhaps not a great idea to add all results to one big list.

Next i would suggest against ng-repeat or add a "track by" to the repeat function.

Check out: http://www.alexkras.com/11-tips-to-improve-angularjs-performance/

Fiddler your queries, the issue is probably rendering all the elements in the dom... Which could be kinda slow ( investigate)

Comment: Pagination helps a tiny bit (brings page memory usage down to 40 MB from 45 MB).   Ng-repeat is a non-issue as this data is going into an Angular-Ui-Grid.  As for Fiddler, I don't have permission to use it in this environment.  I'll keep reading through the link you posted and see if I can't uncover some other hidden nuance.